# Variables won't initialize while using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I don't know many about jQuery but I had to use it for ajax while working in C#(ASP.NET). The problem is that variables bellow won't initialize. Here is the code:

```
var $el = $("table.table").closest('tr');

        var naziv = $el.find("#naziv").text();
        var proizvodjac = $el.find("#proizvodjac").text();
        var cena = parseInt($el.find("#cena").text());
        var sifra = parseInt($el.find("#sifra").text());
```

If I hardcode it (ex. var naziv = "anything"), variables get initialized and I can transfer it without any problem.

Here is also part of the code that I am trying to pull data's from (They have been red from database):

```
  <tr>
            <td id="naziv">
               <p class="sifra">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sifra)</p>
                <b id="naziv">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Naziv)</b>
            </td>

            <td id="proizvodjac">
                Proizvodjac:   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Proizvodjac)
            </td>

            <td id="cena">
                Cena:  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.jedCena)
            </td>
            <td><button id="poruci" class="btn btn-success" onclick="BtnClick()">Poruci</button></td>
            <td>
                <img src="~/Content/slike/bazaMaskica.jpg" />
            </td>

        </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll just post it in case if somebody has the same problem: All I had to do is the find exact button and give click event to him;

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var button = x[i];

            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                let $el = $(this).closest('tr');
                console.log($el.find(".sifra").text());

                let naziv = $el.find(".naziv").text();
                let proizvodjac = $el.find(".proizvodjac").text();
                let cena = parseInt($el.find(".cena").text());
                let sifra = parseInt($el.find(".sifra").text());
                
                var obj = new Object();
                obj = {
                    Naziv: naziv,
                    Proizvodjac: proizvodjac,
                    jedCena: cena,
                    Sifra: sifra
                }
               SubmitForm(obj);
        })
    }
```